# How do I stop users without accounts from cart checkout?

Tags: business-catalyst

I noticed in the checkout process you can checkout without being a member.

How can I prevent this? I need anyone purchasing to have the option to sign in if they have an account or sign up in the checkout process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the output of the islogged in module and then simply hide the add to cart buttons on products and have a note saying "You must be logged in to purchase this item" or something similar.

Here are some useful tips: http://kb.worldsecuresystems.com/654/bc_654.html, with one that includes checking for the module_isloggedin.